# Recording an Espresso Test without having to do a clean install every time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have successfully recorded Espresso tests using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3, but I don't seem to be able to run my app, go to a particular point, and then start the recorder.

It seems as if I can only record tests from a clean install, meaning I have to record the same initial steps again and again.

Any ideas please? Will this functionality be added in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Look into settings under "Espresso test recorder". There are two options "Clear app data before recording" and "Clear app data after recording".

For the record: These checkboxes do exist in Android Studio 4.0 Beta 3

Comment: Android Studio 3.6.3 (current stable as 13/5/2020) has it too.

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution for now will be to record multiple test scenarios at one run 
and later you can divide the single test code into multiple test case and add custom assertions. Event though you have record functionality you can learn and understand how the test cases are coded.

For this release this particular feature is not there but hpefully it may get added in future

If you want to learn more about espresso visit here http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/09/record-test-cases-using-espresso-test.html